# Unitary diagonalization and eigenspace dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

I was trying to diagonalize the matrix:

> $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
> 0 & 0 & i\\
> 0 & i & 0\\
> i & 0 & 0
> \end{array}\right)$

I got two eigenvalues, $\lambda_{1}=i$ and $\lambda_{2}=-i$, and found the eigenspaces:

> $V_{\lambda_{1}=i}=\mathrm{span}\left\{ \left(\begin{array}{c}
> 1\\
> 0\\
> 1
> \end{array}\right)\right\} $
>
> $V_{\lambda_{2}=-i}=\mathrm{span}\left\{ \left(\begin{array}{c}
> 1\\
> 0\\
> -1
> \end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{c}
> 0\\
> 1\\
> 0
> \end{array}\right)\right\} $

Then I composed a unitary matrix after orthonormalising the eigenvectors:
$U=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0
\end{array}\right)\Rightarrow U^{*}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 0 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right)
 $

$U^{*}AU$ does produce a diagonal matrix.

The thing is, I thought the main diagonal should have eigenvalues according to the dimensions $\dim V_{\lambda_{1}=i}=1$ and $\dim V_{\lambda_{2}=-i}=2$:

> $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
> i & 0 & 0\\
> 0 & -i & 0\\
> 0 & 0 & -i
> \end{array}\right)$

But that's not the right diagonal matrix.
Can anyone explain where my error is here?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the diagonal matrix you found, and why is the one you displayed not the right one?

Comment: I found $\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
i & 0 & 0\\
0 & -i & 0\\
0 & 0 & i
\end{array}\right)$ (the right one), and the one displayed isn't the right one by comparing the determinant of the original matrix and this one's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\left(\begin{array}{c}
0\\
1\\
0
\end{array}\right)$ is an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $i$, not $-i$.

Comment: I thought it would be some stupid arithmetic mistake. Thanks!